# How to add a view above all in a controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I would like to add a view above all views and also above navigation bar with storyboard.I added in storyboard But it is appearing like this:

[image: like this]
But I want to add it above navigation bar.

[image]

How to add with storyboard?

Comment: Show us your storyboard and vc hierarchy

Comment: Use UIWindow, I'm not sure how to use it via storyboards, but with code you can add subview to key window.

Comment: @ agent_stack: I edited my question with window hierarchy.Please check once.

Comment: Why don't you just hide the `navigationBar`?

Comment: @Rikh : I can't.It's compulsory in my project.

Comment: You can hide and unhide it depending on which `UIViewController` you are in or programatically at any time. If you want the `UIView` to appear **over** the `UINavigationBar` you are essentially hiding it. If you want a menu like functionality, it is not showing a view on sliding, it is showing two `UIViewController` with `UINavigationBar` inside only one of them.

Comment: Most (if not all) app store accepted apps that display content in the same screen location as the navigation bar do it as an opaque layer *under* the navigation bar.  Do you really want to be different and display an image over a visible navigation bar?

Comment: Actually I'm adding side menu to my project in above screen.So I'm showing a view when user taps menu button in the navigationBar.In this case how can I remove navigationBar ?

Comment: As for as my understanding you want side menu implementation. 
Try this: 
1. Side menu controller (https://github.com/teodorpatras/SideMenuController)
2. SlideMenuController (https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift)
These will make your job easy

Answer (score 0):

As per your req you need to add your custom view into window than and than it will show above `NavigationBar`.

Try to add your view like :

`[objAppDelegate.window addSubView:your customview];`

Set your view frame accordingly window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a view above all you can use `UIWindow`.

Add your subview in `UIWindow` of application delegate. But it is not a best practice to add a view directly on UIWindow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to have your custom Navigation Bar and for that you are using this View. 
Well, if that is the case then you can simply put it on the view heiarchy with all the constraints set like:

1. Leading space to Main View = 0
2. Height = 64
3. Equal height with Main View
4. Center Vertically wrt Main View

Please revert if it's not what you want. Thanks

Comment: Actually I'm adding side menu to my project in above screen.So I'm showing a view when user taps menu button in the navigationBar.In this case how can I remove navigationBar ?

Comment: To create a side bar menu - you can follow this tutorial:
http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/
Also.. to simply hide the navigation bar, you can use:
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

Answer (score 0):

You should User Container view , use all View Controllers inside this container, and set view on the top of Container View

Comment: container view would be the simplest and easy to handle way to do this